# Can you install SharePoint apps for Intranet/Offline Farm?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, solution-package, download

The company I work for will be installing a SharePoint 2013 Farm soon and we are looking into what apps and solutions we could utilize for our Intranet.

As far as I can tell - there is no way to install the SP Apps (like on Store.Office.Com) without SharePoint having a connection to the internet or using the Cloud Based SP.  Is that correct?  Can we only use the packaged .WSP Solutions, and if so where can we find some?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy apps locally if you have the app package.  You upload them into the site catalog and they will be made available to your site collections. You won't be able to utilize apps deployed to the MS store.  You would need to contact the vendor directly to see about obtaining an .app package or code your own and deploy them.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Is there any sort of alternative to the App Store that does offer manual downloads/installations of the packages?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.